Problem predicting arima model, why can't I predict further?
I have a df, I need to learn how to create arima models. I try with auto_arima to search for coefficients p,q,d - I get the following.
Data:
df = df.sort_index()
df = df.asfreq('h') 
df_c4 = df[df.columns[4]]
cnt_data = int(len(df_c4)*0.8)
train_wo_diff = df_c4[0:cnt_data] 
test_wo_diff = df_c4[cnt_data:]
forecast_steps = len(df_c4) - cnt_data

from pmdarima import auto_arima
stepwise_fit = auto_arima(df_c4, trace=True,
suppress_warnings=True)

Output:
`Performing stepwise search to minimize aic
 ARIMA(2,1,2)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=352992.853, Time=4.38 sec
 ARIMA(0,1,0)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=357407.627, Time=0.29 sec
 ARIMA(1,1,0)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=357211.844, Time=0.70 sec
 ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=357144.028, Time=0.87 sec
 ARIMA(0,1,0)(0,0,0)[0]             : AIC=357405.627, Time=0.22 sec
 ARIMA(1,1,2)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=353839.905, Time=6.08 sec
 ARIMA(2,1,1)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=353575.843, Time=11.00 sec
 ARIMA(3,1,2)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=352986.404, Time=5.19 sec
 ARIMA(3,1,1)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=353760.721, Time=5.60 sec
 ARIMA(4,1,2)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=351593.444, Time=8.27 sec
 ARIMA(4,1,1)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=354184.399, Time=4.70 sec
 ARIMA(5,1,2)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=351595.408, Time=8.37 sec
 ARIMA(4,1,3)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=351548.329, Time=8.97 sec
 ARIMA(3,1,3)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=inf, Time=20.41 sec
 ARIMA(5,1,3)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=350054.238, Time=22.69 sec
 ARIMA(5,1,4)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=inf, Time=28.98 sec
 ARIMA(4,1,4)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=inf, Time=27.75 sec
 ARIMA(5,1,3)(0,0,0)[0]             : AIC=350050.593, Time=21.33 sec
 ARIMA(4,1,3)(0,0,0)[0]             : AIC=351546.367, Time=8.00 sec
 ARIMA(5,1,2)(0,0,0)[0]             : AIC=351593.452, Time=7.56 sec
 ARIMA(5,1,4)(0,0,0)[0]             : AIC=inf, Time=26.79 sec
 ARIMA(4,1,2)(0,0,0)[0]             : AIC=351591.487, Time=7.14 sec
 ARIMA(4,1,4)(0,0,0)[0]             : AIC=inf, Time=24.73 sec

Best model:  ARIMA(5,1,3)(0,0,0)[0]          
Total fit time: 260.051 seconds`

Next, I fit the model and try to create a forecast:
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
model = ARIMA(train_wo_diff, order=(5,1,3))
results = model.fit()
print(results.summary())
predict = results.predict()
forecast = results.get_forecast(steps=240).predicted_mean

I get the following:
enter image description here
Question, what am I doing wrong that my model is only predicting me for a very short period of time?
